# Google maps search by address component

Tags: mysql, google-maps

I have implemented a basic google places autocomplete in my web app, for example saying "Heraclion, Crete" and it translates it to the latlng coordinates that I want. I also used the mysql radius example from the api to show nearest entries. I also have locations in a second area of Crete, called "Rethymnon".

The problem now is the following. Supposedly one types just Crete. How can I get all the entries from Heraclion and Rethymnon? My code uses the radius approach as mentioned before. So I need something else to define it in a rectangular area.

Is this possible?

Comment: I haven't seen such a feature

Comment: Hmm, so I would just have to increase the radius to get more results in the same larger area?

Answer (score 0):

If the result contains a viewport (LatLngBounds), you could use that.

[PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry)

geometry: The Place's geometry-related information. This includes:

- location provides the latitude and longitude of the Place.
- viewport defines the preferred viewport on the map when viewing this Place

Comment: So I do get a window of latlong (northeast, northwest, southeast,southwest), how can I use that and find everything inside that rectangle/viewport? For example the whole Crete Island or Texas or the UK?

Comment: What is your data source?  "Everything inside" a particular bounds is a lot of data.

Comment: I am trying to do a custom search for a component based on google maps latlng coordinates. Since reverse geocode can provide upper level information I want to do a search also there. For example it was crete. Crete is an island but its superset is that belongs to greece. So If I type Greece in the google places I would get a rectangle that searched inside it will also show me the entries for crete.